# Does django celery beat auto delete one-off tasks that have been run

Tags: celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I have a reminder model -

```py
class Reminder(models.Model):
    class Types(models.TextChoices):
        CALL = "Call"
        WHATSAPP = "WhatsApp"
        SMS = "SMS"
        EMAIL = "Email"

    workspace = models.ForeignKey(
        "workspaces.Workspace", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="reminders"
    )

    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, choices=Types.choices, null=False, blank=False
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    due_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    remind_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

    data = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, default=dict)

    completed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This is the service to create a reminder -

```py
def create_reminder(**data):
    ...

    one_off_task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(
        name=f"Create and send reminder notification for reminder {reminder.id}",
        interval=IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
            every=1, period=IntervalSchedule.MINUTES
        )[0],
        task="revnew.notifications.tasks.create_and_send_reminder_notification",
        kwargs=json.dumps({"reminder_id": reminder.id}),
        one_off=True,
        start_time=reminder.remind_datetime,
    )
```

When the reminder's periodic task completes running, I want to delete the Periodic task to free up the db.
Is this something that `django-celery-beat` does automatically or will I have to add another periodic task that looks for all the tasks that have been run and delete them?